# Is it bad practice to cover a removed HDD to protect from dust accumulation while it's running as an external?

Tags: hard-drive

I have an internal laptop HDD that I'm using for data recovery out in the open temporarily, and didn't want any dust to collect on it. I've placed an upturned paper plate on top of the drive to hopefully protect against dust, but I was worried covering it up might cause problems

I figure it's less covered now than it would be when inside the actual laptop, but I'm just a bit paranoid.

Is what I'm doing fine?

Answer (score 4):

Unless you have physically open the hard drive to the point where you can see the spinning disks there is no need to cover the drive.  The hard drive has a built-in filter that keeps the dust out.  It won't really harm the drive, but it is unnecessary.  It might cause heat build up, but there is far more heat build up when it is inside the laptop.

If you have opened the hard drive so you can actually see the round hard drive platters your plate won't save you.

Comment: Its impossible for him to have a hard drive that is open where you can see the disks. but im sure you were saying it rhetorically